Why whoami return root on windows10?
OS: Windows10 pro workstation x64 22H2 19045.3803

I never use any wsl such linux thing, why and how to fix?


First, do not post images when plain text will do. Secondly, there is no issue, whoami is working as required. If you do not like it, then remove WSL.

Update your question showing that WSL isn’t installed and I will submit an answer explaining what actually is happening. The screenshot must be in English or an English translation must be provided

@Ramhound Thank you, I don't know how to translate a image, I provide a "enable or disable windows features" dialog screenshot.

Do you have the correct whoami command? What does where.exe whoami print?

@grawity_u1686 You're right, a third-party "whoami.exe" made this, I posted a answer, Thank you.

I see, a third-party "whoami.exe" caused this. Thank you @grawity_u1686.

